# Error GC life time is shorter than transaction duration while writing to TiDB using Spark

Tags: tidb

I am using Apache Spark to write data in batches. The batches are of 1 day. While running the spark job I get this error. I am using MySQL java connector to connect to TiDB cluster. Spark creates 144 parallel tasks for writing.

```
java.sql.SQLException: GC life time is shorter than transaction duration
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3536)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3468)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2107)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2642)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:1610)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.invoke(LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.java:359)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.commit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:821)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:821)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means, the Spark task **Transaction Time** is exceed than the **TiDB**'s `GC Life Time` that means:

> The current read data has been deleted by **TiDB**, since the data's life time exceed than the configed `GC Life Time`

so solution maybe try to increase the `tikv_gc_life_time` by:

```
update mysql.tidb set variable_value='30m' where variable_name='tikv_gc_life_time';
```

see more:

https://github.com/pingcap/docs/blob/master/op-guide/gc.md#configuration-and-monitor